# Find the empty column to fill it with a form

Tags: excel, vba, forms

I've done a Form in VBA and now i want to use this form to fill with data the first empty column from a sheet like in the screenshot.

[image: screenshot]

I need a macro to find and fill the column with TextBox1,2...

This is how i thought:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

   Dim emptyColumn As Long

   emptyColumn = ....

   Cells(emptyColumn, 1).Value = TextBox1.Value  
   Cells(emptyColumn, 2).Value = TextBox2.Value  
   ...  
End Sub
```

**What formula i should use for the "emptyColumn =" ?**

Comment: Welcome to SO, this is not a serving code site. If you are developing a code and have specific question (not already asked in this site), we can help you with that. Please read> [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

and also read> [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Sorry for the unclear question. I've edited it.

Answer (score 0):

there are several ways to find and empty column, I suggest to use a code found in this site:

> http://www.excelhowto.com/macros/delete-blank-empty-columns-use-excel-vba/

```
Sub FindBlankColumns()
'Step1:  Declare your variables.
    Dim MyRange As Range
    Dim iCounter As Long
'Step 2:  Define the target Range.
    Set MyRange = ActiveSheet.UsedRange

'Step 3:  Start reverse looping through the range.
'You can modify this according to your needs.
    For iCounter = MyRange.Columns.Count To 1 Step -1

'Step 4: If entire column is empty then do some stuff.
       If Application.CountA(Columns(iCounter).EntireColumn) = 0 Then
          ' DoSomeStuff
       End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Hope it helps